# Sx is not converting styles to css format for only fill property. how to resolve this?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

This `primary-main` should be converted to color something like `#abcdefg` but it is just pasting `primary-main` as it is

I'm using angular MUI + React

[image: BROWSER]

[image]

Comment: only certain properties support the automatic conversion of palette color names to the configured color value. The easiest ways around this would be to A) use a styled component or B) use the `useTheme` hook to bring in the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Jacob's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4364635/jacob-smit) comment, you would need to reference the theme within your fill key, like so:

```
<menu.icon 
  sx={{
    fill: theme => selected ? theme.palette.primary.main : theme.grey.A400,
    color: selected? 'primary.main' : 'grey.A400',
  }} 
/>
```

Not all properties are [theme aware](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/#theme-aware-properties). In that case you need to bring in the theme object. Don't use the useTheme hook as Jacob mentioned in his comment. Instead just use a function, which will import the [theme object](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/).